# How to find sequence of numbers in list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find if some sequences of numbers are in a list. If so, this tuple should be removed from the list. Numbers must be contiguous to one another.

Example:

list of tuples:

```
list_1 =  [(), (1,), (3,), (2,), (4,), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4), (3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2, 4)]
```

and a second list:

```
list_2 = [1,3,2,4]
```

In this case the elements `(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4)` in `list_1` should be removed, because they contain numbers (not necessarily all of them!)that are contiguous in `list_2`.

I want to check if the elements in list

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    teste = []
    for j in range(len(lista[i])):
        for k in stuff:
            if len(lista[i]) >= 2:
                if lista[i][j] == k:
                    teste.append(k)
                    if len(teste) == 2:
                        lista.remove(lista[i])
                        teste=[]

            else:
                pass
```

With this output:

```
if len(lista[i]) >= 2:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I was trying to check a number, append it to a list check the next one and if it was appended too i would remove the corresponding tuple.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, strictly speaking, `list_1` is a list of tuples, not sets.

Comment: The order matters when you delete a sequence?

Comment: Why shouldn't `(1,)` be removed? It's also a subsequence of `list_2`.

Comment: `()` will, by some definition, be in every possible `list_2` since *all* its values are contained in `list_2`

Comment: `()` should also be removed, as it's also a subsequence of `list_2`.  Can you explicitly write out what you expect the output to be?  Also, your code doesn't make sense in the context of the rest of the question.  What is `lista`?  What is `stuff`?

Comment: This was just an example. In reality I have list_2. list_1 contains all the possible subsets that are possible to be created with list_1. I am interested that this subsets do not contain contiguous numbers of that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, I think this works.

If you want to delete the blank set, just delete it, it's however you define a match.  I added commented code to do that.

Fixed based on your comment

```
print("List 1:", list_1)
print("List 2:", list_2)
removeElements = []
for k in range(len(list_1)):
    #if len(list_1[k]) == 0:
    #    removeElements.append(k)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list_2)):
        for j in range(0, len(list_1[k])):
            if len(list_2) <= i + j:
                break
            count = count + 1
            if list_1[k][j] != list_2[i + j]:
                count = 0
            if count == 2:
                print("removing", list_1[k])
                removeElements.append(k)

removeElements = sorted(set(removeElements))
for i in range(len(removeElements)):
    list_1.pop(removeElements[i] - i)

print("List_1:", list_1)
```

Comment: `range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)`

Comment: ok, if I have different numbers it doesn't work. I tested with:

    list_1 = [(), (1,), (3,), (2,), (4,), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4), (3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2, 4)]

and 

    list_2 = [1, 3, 2, 4]

The matches were:

    ('We have a match at index', 0, 'to index', 1, 'which matches', (1, 3))
    ('We have a match at index', 1, 'to index', 2, 'which matches', (3, 2))
    ('We have a match at index', 2, 'to index', 3, 'which matches', (2, 4))
    ('We have a match at index', 1, 'to index', 3, 'which matches', (3, 2, 4))

Comment: Fixed it and made it remove the elements.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough because the other answer I got was exactly like yours, but `List_1` should not contain the tuples `(1,3,4)` and `(1,2,4)` because these numbers (1 and 3, 2 and 4) are contiguous in `list_2`. –

Comment: Fixed again for that comment

Answer (score 0):

If you grab the `window` recipe from an [old python example](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html) this becomes easy:

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

Then you can just keep the elements that don't appear in any window from `list_2`

```
[t for t in list_1 if t not in window(list_2, len(t))]
```

However, you seem to have special cased tuples of zero or one element, so you'd need to change the filter

```
[t for t in list_1 if len(t) < 2 or t not in window(list_2, len(t))]
```

Comment: i get this message of error: NameError: global name 'islice' is not defined

Comment: `islice` is defined in `itertools`, I've added the import line

Comment: I updated the question because I think I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
list_1 = [(), (1,), (1,2), (1,4)]
y = [list(i) for i in list_1]

list_2=[3,1,2,4]
x = [list_2[0:2], list_2[1:3], list_2[2:4]]

new_list_1 = [tuple(i) for i in y if i not in x[0:]]
```

Output:

```
[(), (1,), (1, 4)]
```